# What does contingent payment mean?

Tags: contracts, payment-terms, payments

I have received a contract that has a two part payment. I'm not sure what to make out of the writing as it says the second part of the payment is contingent upon **(i) COMPANY closing of debt or equity financing round, (ii) the sale of all or substantially all of the COMPANY's assets or majority of the COMPANY's voting power.**

Does this mean they can refuse the pay me if they don't get financing? Are there any loopholes to this statement?

Comment: Why don't you ask the other party instead of an online forum? Nothing wrong or unprofessional to ask them to elaborate on such a clause. Also on a personal note, I would never accept such a clause unless it is some sort of bonus and the main fee already covers my intended revenue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that they will pay you the next payment on the condition that they either launch the company successfully (via a finance round) or they sell the budding company to a bigger fish.

As for loopholes, that will depend on your state (some have protections against this), and tort precedent.

Answer (score 0):

It means you're being baited, unless you've agreed to a highly exceptional situation here.

Normally, nothing in a contract for freelance work *you* have to perform should make the payment contingent on how the client chooses to direct business (i.e. selling off their assets, relocating, and so forth.)  Here's why - what if the client decides to never fulfill the contingency?  You're screwed!

Throw this one back, it reeks of a client trying to pull a fast one.